# Can I play Persona 5 without playing the previous games?

Tags: persona

I'm new to the *Persona* series, so I wanted to know if the *Persona* video games have any relationship to the previous games. I went to other sites but they didn't give me a clear answer.

Can I play *Persona 5* without playing the previous games?

Comment: As per https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/415 and the [help center](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), we allow story questions about anime-style games (but not gameplay questions). Persona 5 seems to fall into that category based on the overall style of the game and the fact that previous games in the series have had anime adaptations. As such I think the question is fine here though it might also be okay on Arqade.

Comment: I know it's an older question, but [this Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/316285/in-what-ways-are-the-individual-persona-games-connected) question is relatable; and a good read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can!

Although *Persona* is a franchise, the games do not depend on each other being totally independent.

This is because even if all games in the franchise have the same essence, each game has a way of addressing this different essence based on its theme.

Already in the introduction, the game already explains everything you need to know about the basics of *Shin Megami Tensei* and how it will affect the functioning of *Persona 5*.

*Note: My boyfriend is playing Persona 5 without having played the other games and is not having the slightest difficulty to understand the story.*

Answer (score 2):

I didn't play *Persona 5* (yet), but I saw a friend's play for quite a stretch of the story so don't take my answer as 100% accurate, but every numeric entry in *Persona* are independent one from another. As usual in any long-running series, some easter eggs and cameos for the fans, but the core story should be fully enjoyable by itself.

It would be different if you asked for something like *Persona 4* and *Persona 4: Arena* or *Persona 4: Dancing All Night*, as they are "in the same numeric entry" so those spin-off games take on the main *Persona 4* story, and thus if you didn't play it, you will feel that you are missing a lot of information, but as pure numeric entries, just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Having checked the *Persona 5* [synopsis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persona_5) in Wikipedia and having played *Persona 4*, the answer to your question would be, "yes, it is safe to play *Persona 5* without having played the previous installments of the game".

The reasons for that is there are these differences between the 2 games.

1. Protagonist and characters

   MC in *Persona 4* is white-haired. The first person to join the team was the son of a department store owner, followed by a tomboy. *Persona 5* MC is black-haired.
2. Place setting

   *Persona 5* was set in Tokyo. *Persona 4* was in a small remote town.
3. Story

   *Persona 4* starts with a mysterious murder that happened during a foggy day and has to do with a TV channel that can only be accessed during certain midnights.

So, with at least those 3 reasons stated above, you can be sure that it is safe to play *Persona 5* without playing the previous installments beforehand. Treat *Persona* series like the *Final Fantasy* series. Every title is its own game, although they do sometimes make references on its previous installment, such as recurring summons, monsters, equipment, names, etc.